# Why does SymPy solve give empty set for high-order polynomial?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, symbols, solver

I have to find the equilibrium points where the [nullclines intersect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEHqh.png). My code is as below.

```
>>> from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
>>> A,M = symbols('A M')
>>> dMdt = Eq(1.05 - (1/(1 + pow(A,5))) - M)
>>> dAdt = Eq(M*1 - 0.5*A - M*A/(2 + A))
>>> solve((dMdt,dAdt), (M,A))
[]
```

Why is it not giving a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You will see why as I work to get the solution.

I'm going to write the equations as e1 and e2 -- use of Eq without a second arg no longer works (or does so with a warning in the latest versions of SymPy):

```
>>> from sympy import solve, nsimplify, factor, real_roots
>>> from sympy.abc import A, M
>>> e1 = (1.05 - (1/(1 + pow(A,5))) - M)
>>> e2 = (M*1 - 0.5*A - M*A/(2 + A))
```

Solve for M using e1

```
>>> eM = solve(e1, M)[0]
```

Substitute into e2

```
>>> e22 = e2.subs(M, eM); e22
-0.5*A - 0.05*A*(21.0*A**5 + 1.0)/((A + 2)*(A**5 + 1.0)) + 0.05*(21.0*A**5 + 1.0)/(A**5 + 1.0)
```

Get the numerator and denominator

```
>>> n,d=e22.as_numer_denom()
```

Find the real roots for this expression (which depends only on A)

```
>>> rA = real_roots(n)
```

Find the corresponding values of M by substituting each into eM:

```
>>> [(a.n(2), eM.subs(A, a).n(2)) for a in rA]
[(-3.3, 1.1), (-1.0, zoo), (-0.74, -0.23), (0.095, 0.050)]
```

That root of A = -1 is spurious -- if you look at your denominator of e1 you will see that such a value causes division by zero. So that root can be ignored. The others can be [verified graphically](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wqzfoelpqi).

Why didn't solve give the solution? It couldn't give the solution for this high-order polynomial in closed form. Even if you factor the numerator described above (and make floats into Rationals with `nsimplify`) you have a factor of degree 7:

```
>>> factor(nsimplify(n))
-(A + 1)*(A**4 - A**3 + A**2 - A + 1)*(5*A**7 + 10*A**6 - 21*A**5 + 5*A**2 + 10*A - 1)/10
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped. The docstring for `solve` doesn't indicate that roots won't be returned in such a case as this. It might be better for the solver to return RootOf solutions.